# Checkbox value returning on

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to determine which checkbox's are checked and if they are checked I want to have a string of all the checked options.

```
 function checkedOptions()
    {
        var checklist = document.getElementById("list");
        var checkboxes = checklist.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        var options;

        for(var i = 1; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].checked == true)
                options += checkboxes[i].value;     
        }

        return options;
    }
```

This code always returns "on" for every check box. I did read some other posts on this topic but they all use jquery and it is something that I am trying to avoid as my workplace is avoiding it. I am not sure how to get the value of this checkbox.

```
<ul class="choice" id="checklist">
    <li><label id="selection" for="list" onMouseOver="mouseOver()" onMouseOut="mouseOut()">
        <input type="checkbox" id="list" checked="true" disabled="true" onChange="checkedOptions()"/>
        (None)
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And the ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) relevant HTML?

Comment: ...preferably both here in the question and as a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your `checkboxes` variable is misleading since it contains all input elements on the page, which is probably why your loop starts from index `i = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your checkbox has no explicit `value` attribute, so it's using the default value of `on`.

If you want it to have a specific value, you need to give it one via `value="my_value"`.

Answer (score 0):

For those following the question's TITLE as opposed to the actual question, this might be a quick answer to the problem of ***checkbox returning ON whether checked or not:***

```
var myVal = ( $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;

alert('myVal is: ' +myVal); //alerts 1 if checked, 0 if not checked
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjyntj1b/)</kbd>